# How do I get a reference to ActionBarDrawerToggle?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-appcompat

I have a Xamarin Forms application that I am porting from a FormsActivity to an AppCompatActivity.  For functional requirements, the hamburger icon should always show, which I have done by using

```
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(nextPage, false);
```

But this does not work with AppCompat and the issue report has sat unaddressed for over a year, so I'm trying to get around the issue with a custom renderer. I can successfully create the icon and display it, but tapping on it does not display the correct behavior.  I'm thinking what I need to do is set the DrawerIndicatorEnabled to true and call SyncState, but I need a reference to the ActionBarDrawerToggle to do that and I haven't figured out how to get it.

**Edit:** This is the bug report with screen shots:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2577

Here is the custom NavigationPageRenderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomNavigationPage), typeof(CustomNavigationPageRenderer))] 

namespace HeaderTest.Droid
{
    public class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer // APPCOMP
    {
        public CustomNavigationPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override Task<bool> OnPushAsync(Page view, bool animated)
        {
            var retVal = base.OnPushAsync(view, false);

            var context = (Activity)Context;
            var toolbar = context.FindViewById<AToolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

            if (toolbar != null)
            {
                var icon = new DrawerArrowDrawable(context)
                {
                    SpinEnabled = false,
                };
                toolbar.NavigationIcon = icon;
            }

            return retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of behaviour that you are getting? It would be great if you could explain with some screenshots.

Comment: could you show your costom renderer ?